# SQL Server 2008 : calculate date and price change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with 3 columns: `art_id`, `date` and `price`. From time to time, the price changes. Dates are not consecutive.

How can I calculate when the price changed, and by how much, for each `art_id`?

Comment: Add some data sample and expected results. Also, what have you tried so far? Do you need actual price and previous most recent price? How price change? is a new record in this table or just an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
DECLARE @artSales TABLE (artid int, dt date, price money);

INSERT @artSales
VALUES 
(1, '20170102', 10), (1, '20170108', 10), (1, '20170112', 8.50), (1, '20170115', 8.50),
(2, '20170102', 20), (2, '20170109', 20), (2, '20170112', 35), (2, '20170116', 40),
(3, '20170101', 500), (3, '20170111', 500), (3, '20170130', 500);

SELECT 
  artid,
  dt,
  oldPrice = price,
  PriceChange =
  CASE 
    LAG(price, 1, price) OVER (PARTITION BY artid ORDER BY dt) 
    WHEN price THEN 0 ELSE 1
  END,
  NewPrice = LAG(price, 1, price) OVER (PARTITION BY artid ORDER BY dt)
FROM @artSales;
```

Results:

```
artid       dt         oldPrice              PriceChange NewPrice
----------- ---------- --------------------- ----------- ---------------------
1           2017-01-02 10.00                 0           10.00
1           2017-01-08 10.00                 0           10.00
1           2017-01-12 8.50                  1           10.00
1           2017-01-15 8.50                  0           8.50
2           2017-01-02 20.00                 0           20.00
2           2017-01-09 20.00                 0           20.00
2           2017-01-12 35.00                 1           20.00
2           2017-01-16 40.00                 1           35.00
3           2017-01-01 500.00                0           500.00
3           2017-01-11 500.00                0           500.00
3           2017-01-30 500.00                0           500.00
```

**UPDATE - FOR PRE-2012 SYSTEMS:**

```
WITH prev AS
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY artid ORDER BY dt), *
  FROM @artSales
)
SELECT 
  as1.artid,
  as1.dt,
  OldPrice    = as1.price,
  PriceChange = CASE WHEN as1.price <> as2.price THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  NewPrice    = ISNULL(as2.price, as1.price)
FROM prev as1
LEFT JOIN prev as2 ON as1.artid = as2.artid AND as1.rn = as2.rn+1;
```

Comment: This looks like perfect solution, only problem is that I am on sql 2008. Sorry for not mentioning it upfront.

Comment: I updated my solution to include a way to do it without LAG OR LEAD

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join with `MIN()`

```
select
    t.art_id,
    ,t.date
    ,t.price
from
    yourTable t
    inner join
    (select art_id, price, min(date) dt
    from yourTable
    group by art_id, price) t2 on t2.dt = t.date and t2.art_id = t.art_id and t2.price = t.price
```

Then, with this result set you can calculate the price change using `LEAD` or `LAG` if you are on 2012+ or using a window function `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `CTE`. Specify which version you're on if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am on sql 2008 and cannot use lag or lead.